# Dúvida sobre formas de agradecimento com uso da Crase

Tags: termos, crase, frases, perguntas

As vezes escrevo e-mails e no final deles eu costumo agradecer, o problema é que eu me deparei com duas possíveis frases de agradecimento e não sei qual das duas está mais correta.

> A primeira:
>
> > "Desde já eu agradeço à atenção"
>
> A Segunda:
>
> > "Desde já eu agradeço pela atenção"

O emprego da crase está correta na primeira forma? caso esteja errado é melhor usar a segunda forma? alguém pode sugerir alguma outra forma de agradecer no final da mensagem?

Comment: Sem acento. O tema de _agradecer_ é objeto direto (portanto aqui sem preposição); o destinatário é que é preposicionado com _a_: Desde já agradeço **a** todos vós a atenção.

Comment: Jonathan, you might want to leave out the eu. **Muito obrigado pela sua atenção** fica bem também. Desde já ficou agradecido pela sua atenção.

Comment: E se escrever outra palavra no meio? Por exemplo: Agradeço especialmente a Adriana e ao Lucas... Agradeço especialmente à Adriana e ao Lucas...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Por que não há crase em ‘a contratantes’](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/9571/por-que-n%c3%a3o-h%c3%a1-crase-em-a-contratantes)

Comment: Olá, boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE. Obrigado pela contribuição, mas note que sua resposta não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação o bastante](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), você poderá deixar comentários em postagens. E, quando tiver uma nova pergunta, faça a postagem como pergunta e não como resposta a uma pergunta já existente (o site tem o formato "1 pergunta + resposta(s)", sem diálogo). Dito isso, o "especialmente" não muda nada e o "a" continua craseado (assim como o "o" antes de "Lucas" mantém o "a" e permanece "ao").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não, não está correto.  Com crase, o seu agradecimento é dirigido a uma pessoa chamada Atenção.  Você agradece a alguém por algum favor ou gentileza.

- Agradeço a sua atenção
- Agradeço à (a + a) professora pela explicação que me deu.
- Agradeço a gentileza
- Agradeço à senhora pela gentileza.

> - [**a·gra·de·cer**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/agradecer)

> - verbo transitivo

1. Dar agradecimentos por; retribuir com agradecimentos.

> - verbo intransitivo
>   2. Exprimir agradecimentos.