# Por que não há crase em ‘a contratantes’

Tags: crase, regência

Por que não há crase em ‘a contratantes’ na seguinte frase?

> Entregaram a contratantes o serviço

Comment: Se você colocar a Tecla Internacional na sua máquina, poderia digitar os acentos. crase se usa quando há uma preposição a junto com o artigo a ou as.

Answer (score 3):

Há crase caso se trate de contratantes específicas: nesse caso além da preposição "a" (que aqui poderia ser substituída por "para") haveria também o artigo definido "as":

> Entregaram às (= para as) contratantes o serviço.

Enquanto na frase original (sem crase) tem-se contratantes genéricas.

Para maiores detalhes e outros exemplos, cf. a [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9576/2764) de ANeves e, e.g., [Qual a forma correta de utilizar o "à"? ("a" com crase)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/142/2764).

Answer (score 2):

**Entreguei às avós** a policia.

*Segue a regra*: **entregar algo a alguém** **seguido de um artigo feminino**.
Ou seja dois "as" juntinhos.

**Entregaram a contratantes o serviço.** não segue a regra.

Ou seja, *entregaram a contratantes* e não, por exemplo, *a trabalhadores independentes.* A preposição **a** em si não requer uma crase.

Answer (score 1):

Porque o "a" nessa frase é apenas uma preposição, e não uma contração.

> Entregaram a contratantes o serviço

A resposta de stafusa explica bem a diferença de significado entre haver apenas uma preposição, ou haver uma preposição "craseada" com um artigo.

## Análise do problema

Entendamos analiticamente o problema:

Crase é a «[contracção ou fusão de sons vogais num só](https://dicionario.priberam.org/crase)" [Priberam].
Por [metonímia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meton%C3%ADmia), é por vezes também chamado *crase* ao acento usado para indicar essa fusão (`), ou à palavra resultante (à, às, àquele, etc).

Para "haver crase" (à em vez de a), teria de haver uma contração: da preposição "a" com um artigo definido "a", resultando em "à".

Mas o artigo definido **tem** de ter concordância de género e número com o substantivo que o segue.
Sendo "contratantes", a crase nunca seria a+a=à.
Teria de ser uma frase diferente:

- Ou: entregaram a + as contratantes = entregaram **às** contratantes;
- Ou: entregaram a + os contratantes = entregaram **aos** contratantes;
- Ou: entregaram a + a **contratante** = entregaram à contratante (singular).