# Tem crase em "diz pra ele fazer uma visita à gente aqui"?

Tags: gramática, crase

Não lembro de jamais ter colocado crase em "à gente" ou ter visto a crase aí.  Sei que visitar é verbo transitivo direto, mas a gente usa a preposição quando diz---farei uma visita a ele amanhã.  Sendo assim, a frase "diz pra ele fazer uma visita à gente aqui" tem a preposição.  Portanto, teremos que adicionar o acento grave aí.  Ou será que estou totalmente por fora? Obrigado!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Por que não há crase em ‘a contratantes’](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/9571/por-que-n%c3%a3o-h%c3%a1-crase-em-a-contratantes)

Comment: Não há crase em "a contratantes" porque contratantes não só é plural, mas é palavra masculina.  A crase é uma elisão do artigo /a/ com a preposição /a/.  Se colocarmos o artigo em "contratantes", ficamos com "aos contratantes".  Não é o caso da pergunta aqui.

Comment: Para a crase, é preciso a + a ( artigo definido no feminino e a preposição). Acho que o pessoal errou no seu exemplo.

Comment: Se entendi bem, não foi você quem colocou a marca de duplicata.  (Achei que tinha sido.)  Talvez não tenha entendido seu último comentário.

Comment: Sim, fui eu. Tá errado a duplicata ou não funciona na sua opinião? Posso deletar o link.

Comment: Ah, sim, agora compreendi.  Sim, a duplicata não se aplica à pergunta, não.  Eu marquei não na pergunta e aí achei que assim você teria minha resposta.  Perdão.  E obrigado!

Comment: @Lambie Esta pergunta não deveria ser marcada como duplicata de [Por que não há crase em ‘a contratantes’?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/9571/592), pois suas respostas não se aplicam à presente pergunta, *especialmente* porque no presente caso há crase.

Comment: fazer uma visita a gente, não leva crase. agradecer à gente, sim. :)

Comment: @Lambie Eu não acho que você deveria postar isso como resposta; mas, se acha mesmo que não tem crase no exemplo, por que escrever no campo de comentários em vez de escrever uma resposta?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O termo `a` na expressão coloquial `a gente` é um artigo. Portanto, craseia-se `à gente`:

> Diz pra ele fazer uma visita à gente aqui.

Note que a crase não é um acento grave, como sugerido no texto da pergunta.

Comment: O seu exemplo: "fazer uma visita a gente aqui*, não leva crase.

Comment: @Lambie Como você categoriza `a`, sintaticamente, na frase acima?

Comment: artigo determinado. O problema na sua frase é que visita termina em a mas não é um verbo que leva a: agradecer a [alguém] + as meninas, virá: agradecer às meninas por causa do verbo que leva a **e** porque as meninas é um feminino.

Comment: @GuiImamura, perfeito.  A pergunta realmente sugere que a crase é o acento.  (Falha minha.)  Isso me traz um outra pergunta---que é pedir por uma referência desse próprio fato.  Por exemplo, já ouvi dizer que "gostoso" tem crase, mas evidentemente não tem acento.  (Tem crase porque ocorre a elisão do /o/ de gosto com o sufixo /oso/.)  Vou fazer [a pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/9967) em separado.

Comment: @user1145880 Não, gostoso não tem crase. Não em português, pelo menos.

Comment: @Lambie Ainda não me respondeu por que não posta a sua resposta, se não concorda com a minha. *Embora eu já saiba porquê*.

Comment: Por que as preguntas sobre crase desse OP são confusas. Ele fala: "diz pra ele fazer uma visita à gente aqui" tem a preposição", Depois fala em acento grave.   Além disso, tambem colocou outra pergunta com uma confusão semelhante.