# Referência para crases em palavras em que o acento não aparece

Tags: morfologia, crase

Já ouvi dizer que "gostoso" tem crase, mas evidentemente não tem acento (grave).  Tem crase porque ocorre a elisão do /o/ de gosto com o sufixo /oso/.  Estou procurando por uma referência que disserte sobre esse fato explicitamente (e com exemplos, se possível).  Consegue indicar uma referência?

Comment: Quando digo "referência", estou procurando uma gramática publicada por uma editora como, por exemplo, a "Gramática Escolar" de Evanildo Bechara.  Você consegue apontar uma?

Comment: O que é crase para você? //Contração ou fusão de sons vogais num só.
"crase", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2024, https://dicionario.priberam.org/crase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tem crase porque ocorre (...)

Na morfologia vai considerar-se que o nome gost**o** termina com o índice temático **-o** e o sufixo derivacional é **-os(o/a)**. Portanto não é preciso recorrer a uma explicação fonética porque o sufixo escolhe radicais, neste caso **gost-** sem o índice temático. Fica portanto:

- radical+sufixo+índice temático
- **gost**+**os**+**o**

Em obras de referência, um exemplo com um radical atemático e outro a terminar com o índice temático **-e**:

> De modo diverso, o sufixo -os-
> junta-se a nomes e forma adjetivos (gas/gasoso; deleite/deleitoso)
>
> - página 63 in *Gramática Derivacional do Português*, Alexandra Soares Rodrigues, Isabel Pereira, Graça Rio-Torto. Imprensa da Universidade de Coimbra, 2016.

e no mesmo livro:

> ##### 3.1.3.2 Adjetivos sufixados em -ent(o/a), -os(o/a) e -ud(o/a)
>
> Outros sufixos encontram-se mais acantonados na expressão de
> posse (de algo ±alienável) de manifestação de uma propriedade,
> como -ent- (ciumento, lamacento, sum(ar)ento), -os- (brioso, espaçoso)
> e -ud- (raçudo, sisudo, sortudo)
>
> (amoroso, ardiloso, ciumento, pesaroso, ternurento),
>
> - páginas 252-253

e mais à frente:

> ##### 3.3.9 Adjetivos sufixados em -os(o/a)
>
> **O sufixo -os(o/a) anexa-se ao radical das bases** (queixar>queixoso)
> e forma adjetivos (humilhoso, imaginoso, necessitoso)
>
> - página 279

Comment: Agora é minha vez de encontrar um exemplar da referência e verificar lá.  Muito obrigado!

Comment: Crase é: Contração ou fusão de sons vogais num só.
"crase", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2024, https://dicionario.priberam.org/crase. gostoso tem isso? Eu acho que não.